# Perigee location?

Tags: launch, orbital-elements

Suppose I throw a ball eastward from Kennedy and reduce the earth to a point so that the ball can trace an ellipse around it.

Because I threw the ball eastward (no vertical or northern velocity components), I expect the launch site to be either the perigee or the apogee of the resulting orbital ellipse.

But which?

I feel strongly that it should be the apogee, meaning the perigee would be 180 degrees displaced from the launch site.

Is this right?

Comment: I assume you aren't changing the Earth's mass when you're reducing it to a point (& there's no atmosphere). What's the ball's launch speed (don't forget to include the speed it inherits due to the Earth's rotation), in particular, is it faster or slower than circular orbit speed at that altitude?

Comment: Same mass, baseball speed, say---slower than orbital speed (like the rest of us things stranded on the surface of the earth) :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming atmosphere isn't a consideration.

The **azimuth** angle (north-east-south-west orientation) doesn't matter at all for this question -- it determines the orientation of the ellipse, but has little effect on  its shape, and none on the perigee-apogee question.

If the **elevation** angle is zero -- i.e. you're throwing it with a perfectly horizontal initial speed -- then the answer depends on the velocity you throw it with.

If it's less than circular orbit velocity (which is very much the case, assuming you're an ordinary human throwing an ordinary ball, since circular orbit is around 7800 m/s), then the release point would be apogee, as you guess, and perigee will be 180 degrees around orbit. The perigee will be very low over the point-Earth for a human's throw; the ellipse will be very long and narrow. In this case, most of the ball's initial velocity will come from the eastward rotation of the Earth -- around 400 m/s at Kennedy (463 m/s times the cosine of the latitude of the site). A thrown ball might gain another 30 m/s or so.

If you throw the ball faster, the perigee will be higher; as you approach circular orbit speed, the perigee altitude approaches the apogee altitude.

If you throw it at exactly circular velocity, apogee and perigee altitude are the same and their locations become undefined.

If you throw it faster, then the release point is the perigee and the opposite side of the ellipse is apogee.

If the elevation angle is nonzero -- i.e. if you throw it at an upward or downward angle -- then the release point won't be the apogee. If you throw it upward, the top of its arc will be the apogee, probably no more than a few meters away from the release. If you throw it downward, it will reach apogee on its return after almost a full orbit, a little ways behind you. (With no forces applied to the ball after release other than single-point gravity, it would pass through exactly the release point after one orbit.)

A simulation like Kerbal Space Program might be helpful for you to develop your intuition about this kind of orbital mechanics question.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks, @Russel_Borogove. You actually answered a second question I had when you brought up throwing at an angle.

Comment: @user39728 Welcome to Stack Exchange! Just a helpful tip: if you leave a comment under someone's post, you don't need to `@` them, just write the comment. They'll receive a notification that you've commented automatically. If it's to someone else who has commented under a post, then `@` them but delete spaces completely, don't replace a space with an underscore. '_'  From [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/303080) see [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/303080) Try it here now; if you start a comment and type `@u` you will see the autocomplete appear

Comment: Thanks @uhoh---I didn't know! This will come in handy.

Comment: Probably beyond the scope, but if the Earth is reduced to a point mass (ie a black hole a cm across) will relativity be significant in the orbit of a ball. I'd suspect that, provided you include the rotation speed of the earth (and you aren't at the pole) then the perigee will be far enough from the point mass that relativity isn't an issue.